# makefile "%:" in prerequisite

Tags: makefile

```
.
├── dira
│   └── Makefile
├── dirb
│   └── Makefile
└── Makefile
```

```
// Makefile
subdir     := $(sort $(subdir) dira dirb)
# $(info $(subdir))
$(subdir): %:
    @echo $*
    @make -s -C $* run

all: $(subdir)
.PHONY: $(subdir) all
```

```
// dira/Makefile
run:
    @echo "a"
```

```
// dirb/Makefile
run:
    @echo "b"
```

These are my minimal examples. I know that "$*" matches what "%" matches. But this rule is a bit strange.
I want to know what "%:" means in `$(subdir): %:`.

subdir is already a pseudo-target, why not use "$@"? Is there a special purpose for this?

I've checked the manual for match-anything, secondary extensions.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for your timely reply. It solved my doubts. I guess I'm still too new to make, the answer is in the manual.